# FMCW or FSK radar signal processing using an Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino, radar, fsk

I have been trying to build a car detection system with range measurement using an Arduino Nano, an AgilSense AP88 (this provides I/Q output, butI am using only the I output,) and an MPU4725 DAC (frequency regulation using a VCO pin on the radar.) The high level schematic looks like this:

[image: High level diagram of the whole system]

The main issue is, that since the Arduino Nano is single core, the frequency modulation and frequency measurement cannot be done at the same time. I am using the Arduino's `pulseIn()` function to measure the frequency, but this causes a long delay in the frequency modulation using the external DAC.

Voltage regulation progress is shown below.

[image: Voltage regulation progress]

After the failure with FMCW, I decided to look into FSK modulation, but I was not able to find any useful information on if or how it is possible to measure phase shift using only an Arduino Nano.

Is it even possible to process the signals from such a radar using an Arduino?

If so, do I need any more specific hardware or is it possible to make it work using the right software?

Comment: You didn't show a sketch. Are you using a timeout on the PulseIn call? Otherwise, the call will block until the pulse has happened.

Comment: State precisely what you are wanting to do. At a guess you need to generate a ramp to modulate the transmitter whilst sampling the I and Q using the adc. You should be able to sample at around 30kHz on the AVR based Arduino. Considering there are many cheaper and much more performant alternatives to the AVR, I’d suggest you investigate these. And don’t use Pulsein.

Comment: The exact thing I want to do is measure the distance of the object using radar. It does not have to be necessarily Arduino Nano, but it is one of the cheapest options. Since I do need to regulate sampled frequency I would need a DAC and solution to measure the freqnecy or phase so I can calculate the distance.